# Can git-range-diff's results be presented in an external tool like we get with git-difftool?

Tags: git, diff, git-difftool, git-range-diff

I just learned about [`git-range-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff) which looks very promising to help understand changes done to the history during a rebase. However I'd like to know whether there's a solution to get the results to be shown in an external diffing tool (such as `pycharm64 diff` for example).

I've looked this up and browsed through `git-range-diff`'s, `git-diff`'s and `git-difftool`'s docs but haven't found one yet. I'll continue looking and will post the answer here if I find it.

Comment: At this time, there is no built-in support for external diff tools for `git range-diff`, as far as I know.